# How do I access OpenSSL using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, openssl

I want to use some OpenSSL functionality from Node.js which is not provided using Node's `crypto` module, e.g. create a CSR.

The only solution I currently have is using a child process to run the `openssl` command line utility, but this is not the ideal solution as you are dependent on certain paths, ...

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate it on linux or mac you can use
https://github.com/andris9/pem

If you want to do it own windows you can use openssl binaries.

Of course in both cases child process has been used. I think that's the only way you can get it